# $R$ be a Noetherian semi local ring such that $R/N(R)$ is complete $\mathrm{Jac}(R)$-adically, then $R$ is complete $\mathrm{Jac}(R)$-adically.

Tags: commutative-algebra, filtrations, topological-rings, formal-completions

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian semi local ring, and $I=\text{N}(R)$, $J=\text{Jac}(R)$. If $R/I$ is complete w.r.t. $J$-adic filtration then we have to show that $R$ is complete in $J$-adic filtration.

Thus we have to show that the natural map $f:R \to \varprojlim R/J^{n}$ is an isomorphism while we are given that $g:R \to \varprojlim R/(I+J^{n})$ is an isomorphism. By Artin-Rees lemma we already have $\bigcap_{n \geq 1}J^{n}=(0)$, hence $f$ is injective. It remains to show that $f$ is onto. Lets consider a coherent sequence $(x_n) \in \varprojlim R/J^{n}$ so that $x_{n+1}-x_n \in J^{n}$ which implies that $x_{n+1}-x_n \in I+J^{n}$, i.e., $(x_n)$ is an element in $\varprojlim R/(I+J^{n})$. Since $g$ is onto there is an element $x \in R$ such that $x-x_n \in I+J^{n}$ for all $n \geq 1$. From here I can't complete the proof. I couldn't use that $J$ is intersection of only finitely many maximal ideals and $I \subset J$; also the fact $\bigcap_{n \geq 1}(I+J^{n})=I$ due to the map $g$ is injective. I need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The semi-local assumption is perhaps misleading because it is totally superfluous.

Much more generally, the following is true:

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring, $I, J$ ideals of $R$ such that $R/I$ is $J$-adically complete and $R$ is $I$-adically complete.  Then $R$ is $J$-adically complete.

For a complete reference, see [Stacks, 10.96.10](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BNH).

For Noetherian rings, the nilradical is nilpotent.  Any module is complete with respect to any nilpotent ideal, so in particular the cited fact implies that **for Noetherian rings, completeness always lifts modulo the nilradical.**

Comment: I had seen the lemma in stack project that you've referred. But I believe it has some independent solution, for example the way I am trying to prove it.

Comment: @user371231 why do you want a special proof for this case? Also, have you tried the local case yet? No point getting stuck on the semi-local problem if you haven't successfully worked the local one.

Comment: Yes I tried in the local case, but it didn't come. BTW in your abovementioned link I've some doubts. How do one get "By lemma $10.96.2$ $B/IB$ is the $J$-adic completion of $A/I$"?

Comment: I'd probably just phrase it in terms of 10.96.1, which has basically the same contents as 10.96.2.  Since $R/I$ is f.g., by the lemma, ${R/I}^\wedge = R^\wedge \otimes R/I$.  Recall that for any ring $R$, ideal $I$, and module $M$ it's always the case that $M \otimes R/I = M/IM$.  In particular here $R/I$ is complete so $R/I = R^\wedge/IR^\wedge$.

Comment: @user371231 note that, as in your OP, you can also nix the end of the proof involving faithful flatness given in the stacks reference and instead just appeal to Krull intersection to show that the completion is injective.  So all you have left to do is confirm that $R^\wedge$ is f.g. and apply Nakayama to get surjectivity.

Comment: Following the notation in the stack link, I am trying to understand why  $B/IB$ is the $J$-adic completion of $A/I$ ? Not clear to me yet. Can you elaborate a bit ?

Comment: Is it true that $A/I$ is $I+J$-adically complete ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109258/discussion-between-user371231-and-badam-baplan).